# When catching errors in Express route how do I bypass first res.render to avoid error, "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

**Background:** The simplified test code below uses Express and Mongoose.

**Question:** I set up the `.then` statement to throw an error for testing.  When an exception is thrown my error handling middleware is triggered with `next()` but not before `res.render('index', { doesUserExist });` is hit.  This line results in the error, "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" because in my error handling middleware `res.render('error_page', { err });` is also called.  What part of my code should I change to eliminate the error?

**Followup:**  Do I need more than a slight shift in my approach?  Am I using the completely wrong pattern to perform this action efficiently/effectively?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    (async function() { 
        let doesUserExist = await User.exists( { name: 'steve' })
            .then( function(result) {
                throw 'simulated error';
            })
            .catch( function(error) {
                next(new Error(error));
            });
        res.render('index', { doesUserExist });
    })();
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

    res.render('error_page', { err });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of an async function without a catch block

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    (async function () {
        try {
            let doesUserExist = await User.exists( { name: 'steve' });
            if (doesUserExist) {
                throw 'simulated error';

            } else {
                next(new Error(error));

            }
            res.render('index', { doesUserExist });
        } catch (err) {
            return next(err)
        }
    })();
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error_page', { err });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of next write return next(new Error(error)). In this way it wont execute any further code and go to the error middleware

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function wrapper to catch all the errors and send them to the error middleware:

```
const asyncWrap = fn =>
  function asyncUtilWrap (req, res, next, ...args) {
    const fnReturn = fn(req, res, next, ...args)
    return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next)
  }
```

Then you can reutilize it in all your controllers, making the app much cleaner:

```
app.get('/', asyncWrap(async function(req, res, next) {
        let doesUserExist = await User.exists( { name: 'steve' }) //*
            .then( function(result) {
                throw 'simulated error'; // This error is automatically sent to next()
            })
            .catch( function(error) {
                next(new Error(error)); // This error works normally
            });
        res.render('index', { doesUserExist });
});
```

*You shouldnt combine await and then/catch syntax by the way.